# WPF привязка

Tags: wpf

Есть некий класс, например:

```
class Person
{
     public string Name {get; set;}

     public List<Car> Cars {get; set;}
}
```

Есть ViewModel

```
class ViewModel
{
    public List<Person> People {get; set;}
}
```

Далее ViewModel биндится к гриду.

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People, Mode=OneWay}">
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя человека"              
                                     Binding="{Binding Path=Name}">
                 </DataGridTextColumn>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Кол-во авто"                     
                               Binding="{Binding Path=Cars.Count, Mode=OneWay}">
                 </DataGridTextColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Собственно сам вопрос. Во время выполнения программы, свойство Cars класса Person может изменяться, т.е. машины могут добавляться в коллекцию и удаляться из нее. Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении свойства Cars, в гриде автоматически отображалось верное количество автомобилей. На данный момент, при изменении коллекции в гриде не отображаются новые данные.

Comment: юзайте ObservableCollection

Comment: А без ObservableCollection не обойтись? Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: И еще вопрос не по теме немного. Если в гриде выделить строку, а потом перенести фокус на элемент текстбокс скажем, то выделение строки в гриде пропадает. Как сделать так, чтобы строка в гриде все равно оставалась выделенной не смотря на то, что фокус уже находится в другом элементе.

Comment: >А без ObservableCollection не обойтись?

а чем он вам не угодил?

Comment: Всем угодил, просто интересно если еще какие варианты.

Comment: ну можете делать все вручную, как в WinForms

Comment: Ясно. А как сделать так, чтобы выделенная в гриде строка не теряла выделение, когда фокус переносится на другой элемент?

Т.е. как я хочу чтобы работало. Пользователь выделяет строку в гриде, затем переходит в текстбокс и что-то там пишет. Так вот, в данный момент если выделить в гриде строку и затем начать что-то писать в текстбокс, то строка в гриде потеряет свое выделение. Мне нужно чтобы она не теряла.

Answer (score 2):

Вот простенький пример с ObservableCollection:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Name="Combo" Width="70" Height="100" Grid.Row="1"  />

    <Button Name="Add" Width="70" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Click="Btn_Click"  Content="Add" />
    <Button Name="RemoveBtn" Width="70" Height="25" Grid.Row="3" Click="RemoveBtn_Click" Content="Remove"  />
</Grid>
```

Модель представления:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ListString"); 
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Класс окна (в данном случае оставил все на обработчиках, а не на командах, поскольку они здесь роли не играют):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel VM { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        VM = new ViewModel();
        VM.Items = new ObservableCollection<string>(new [] { "first", "second", "third"  });
        Combo.ItemsSource = VM.Items;
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.Items.Add("new item");
    }

    private void RemoveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Что же касается дополнительного вопроса про грид, то лучше сделайте его отдельным вопросом

Comment: За пример спасибо. С командами и ViewModel понемногу разобрался. Вроде начинает потихоньку проясняться как работать с WPF используя паттерн MVVM.